# Matplotlib cannot produce a plot with errorbars in a timely manner despite the fact that MWE can do it

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, plot, axes, errorbar

I have written a code that shows takes forever to plot an errorbar plot using matplotlib package. However, when I actually make it into a MWE where I have evaluated x, y, xerr and yerr and manually insert them into the errorbar line, the code runs smoothly. These values are exactly the values taken from the original code. I don't know why the original code doesn't produce plots while the following MWE actually produces it. Here is the example that is working:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy import *
from matplotlib.ticker import MaxNLocator

my_x=np.array([20.05, 20.15, 20.25, 20.35, 20.45, 20.55, 20.65, 20.75, 20.85, 20.95, 21.05, 21.15, 21.25, 21.35, 21.45, 21.55, 21.65, 21.75, 21.85, 21.95, 22.1,  22.3])
my_x_err_lolim, my_x_err_uplim=np.array([0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.1,  0.1]), np.array([0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.1,  0.1])
my_y=np.array([0.6372361,  0.74868714, 0.71499067, 0.73164494, 0.66726811, 0.58116623, 0.50617463, 0.42101772, 0.34221605, 0.29805772, 0.21592373, 0.17151431, 0.14598236, 0.09210864, 0.06828108, 0.05423759, 0.04408597, 0.02110087, 0.01564229, 0.00350187, 0.00175509, 0.00175509])
my_y_err_lolim, my_y_err_uplim=np.array([0.23176874, 0.27230452, 0.2600488, 0.26610612, 0.24269166, 0.2113756, 0.18593597, 0.1546548, 0.12570814, 0.10948721, 0.08039986, 0.06386388, 0.05528444, 0.0355843, 0.02698123, 0.02197097, 0.01785867, 0.00958897, 0.00859537, 0.00445642, 0.0022335, 0.0022335]), np.array([0.23176874, 0.27230452, 0.2600488, 0.26610612, 0.24269166, 0.2113756, 0.18593597, 0.1546548, 0.12570814, 0.10948721, 0.08039986, 0.06386388, 0.05528444, 0.0355843, 0.02698123, 0.02197097, 0.01785867, 0.00958897, 0.00859537, 0.00445642, 0.0022335, 0.0022335])


pdf_HI, (ax1) = plt.subplots(1, 1, sharex=True, sharey=False, figsize=(14,20))

ax1.errorbar(my_x, my_y, xerr = array([my_x_err_lolim, my_x_err_uplim]), yerr = array([my_y_err_lolim, my_y_err_uplim]), ecolor = 'blue', fmt= 'b.', elinewidth = 1, capsize = 2, linestyle = '', label='')
ax1.vlines(20.3, ymin=-0.1, ymax=3, colors='blue', linestyles='dotted', linewidths=2, label='DLA Column Density')
ax1.hlines(1, xmin=0, xmax=22.3, colors='black', linestyles='dotted', linewidths=2, label='')
ax1.hlines(0, xmin=0, xmax=22.3, colors='black', linestyles='dotted', linewidths=2, label='')

ax1.legend(loc='upper right', ncol=6, fontsize=15)
ax1.set_xlim([19, 23])
ax1.set_ylim([-0.1, 1.1])
ax1.yaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(prune='upper')) 
ax1.set_ylabel('$Y$', fontsize=22)
ax1.set_xlabel('X$', fontsize=22)
ax1.set_xscale("linear", nonposx='clip')
ax1.set_yscale("linear", nonposy='clip')
ax1.xaxis.set_tick_params(width=2)
ax1.yaxis.set_tick_params(width=2)
ax1.get_xaxis().tick_bottom()  
ax1.get_yaxis().tick_left()



pdf_HI.subplots_adjust(top=0.996,bottom=0.101,left=0.076,right=0.997)
plt.setp([a.get_xticklabels() for a in pdf_HI.axes[:-1]], visible=True)
pdf_HI.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

I have printed out all x, y, xerr and yerr to make sure they are all in the same consistent patter. So, what is so special about the MWE that makes it work?

Comment: That is sure not a minimal example. Remove everything that is not needed to reproduce the error.

Comment: Thanks, it's weird that MWE works but not in the context of my original code. The only thing I have changed from original to the MWE is really putting arrays manually into their place. In fact, surprisingly, I have produced these arrays from the original code.

Comment: One obvious difference between the working code and the non working one is that the data in the working code is all below 25, while in the non-working one it goes up to 1*10^22.

Comment: the real data are in units of 10^ something smaller than 25. When I want to plot them in linear-linear scale, I am making sure than they are represented as numbers smaller than 25 on x-axis. This is exactly the same thing between two. I fixed that and now they are exactly the same.

Comment: Still, the original one doesn't work:(

Comment: I am printing all arrays intentionally before plotting and I see that they are all correct.

Comment: I got your point. One of the lines were not in the same domain as errorbar. You're correct. I had correct errorbar but not a correct plot for horizontal lines. It's interesting! I have not seen this before.

Comment: I wish there was some sort of error message!

Comment: Essentially this is [a known bug](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/5918). The problem is that there isn't really any error to be thrown, it's just that the longer the dotted/dashed line, the longer it takes to render.